# Для чего нужны promise?

Tags: javascript, java, php

У меня два вопроса, основной - для чего нужны promise?
И второй, более важны для меня, умеют ли они делать следующие: создать цепочку вызовов методов и чтобы последующий метод, обрабатывал возращённое значение предыдущего? То есть

```
new Promise()
    .then(a, 10)
    .then(b)
    .then(c);

    function a(n)
    {
        return n + 5;
    }

    function b(n)
    {
        n + 4;
    }

    function c(n)
    {
        n + 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В двух словах не ответить, почитайте, посмотрите:

- http://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/
- https://tech.yandex.ru/events/yagosti/fronttalks-ekb-jul-2013/talks/981/

Во вторых, да, можно:

```
new Promise(function (resolve) { resolve(1); })
    .then(function (x) {
        return x + 1;
    })
    .then(function (x) {
        return x * 3;
    })
    .then(function (x) {
        console.log(x); // 6
    });
```

Comment: @RubaXa, Спасибо! Пока читать и если останутся вопросы, то спрошу :)

Comment: Обещания наше все, сними код становится гибче и прозрачнее, осваивайте.

Comment: @vas посмотрите .when() я долго тупил как-раз на эту тему, почему-то пропускал when().

    when(a,b,c).then(d)

Comment: @eicto, а можно на человеческом языке пояснить? на .ru ?))))

Comment: А это open source? Если да, и кто-нибудь знает, где его можно посмотреть, дайте ссылку.